# Creating a graph with relative distance (C#)

Tags: c#, charts

I have the following problem. I create a chart with migradoc in c#.

Suppose I have the following points for my xAxis:
20.4, 20.6, 30.6, 100.4, 200.3

The problem is that it sets every xpoint in the series on an equal distance in the chart.

While what I need is a graph who sets the xpoints on a relative distance. For example, the distance between points 20.6 and 30.6 needs to be way smaller than the distance between 30.6 and 100.4. (The points always differ, as do the number of points)

One way to make the distance good is to add extra points between the existing points. For example the first step is 0.2 extra, the second step is 10.0 extra. So I want to add for example 50 extra points between this step, so that the distance is relative the same.

This is the only thing I can come up with, can somebody give me some advice how to accomplish this? (Or another possible solution?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method worked out for me. I first made the distances relative:

```
Int64[] relAfstand = new Int64[afstand.Count()];
    for(int i = 0; i < afstand.Count(); i++){
        double tussenRel = Convert.ToDouble(afstand[i]);
        double eindRel = Convert.ToDouble(afstand[afstand.Count()-1]);
        double beginRel = Convert.ToDouble(afstand[0]);

        double Rel = (((eindRel - beginRel) - (eindRel - tussenRel)) / (eindRel - beginRel));
        relAfstand[i] = Convert.ToInt64((Rel)*100);
    }
```

Then I converted the data to scale with relative with the same factor as the distances:

```
List<double> ConvertedData = new List<double>();
int c = 0;
int c2 = 1;
double steps = 0;
bool calcSteps = false;
bool calcDistance = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (calcDistance == false) { 
        distance.Add(i);
    }

    if (relAfstand[c] == i) {
        ConvertedData.Add(data[c]);
        calcSteps = false;
        c2 = 1;
        c++;
    }else {
        if (calcSteps == false) {
            steps = ((data[c] - data[c-1])/(relAfstand[c] - relAfstand[c-1]));
            calcSteps = true;
        }
        ConvertedData.Add(data[c-1] + (steps * c2));
        c2++;
    }
}
calcDistance = true;
```

Probably not the best workaround, but it works. Since the percentages can come close together I scale both now with around 200-300 instead of 100.